# Denegar logeo en phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

Estamos desarrollando una base de datos en phpmyadmin en un host que compramos, para ello tenemos un usuario creado "Prueba" con solo permisos de "Select", este solo lo utilizamos para crear la cadena de conexión en nuestra aplicación.

La problemática resulta en que hay una parte del programa en donde se ve el usuario, contraseña e ip del servidor (hay un motivo por el que necesitamos no ocultarla), lo que queremos es que si la persona toma esa IP y quiere logearse en el phpMyAdmin denegar que tenga permiso de hacerlo, o en su defecto ocultar todas las tablas que se deseen.

Todo lo encontrado de información referente de como prohibir el acceso a ciertos usuarios de logear al panel fue quitando permiso de IP o permitiendo ciertas IP de ingresar, pero necesitamos que las IPs sean dinamicas, asi que esto no nos funciona, queremos elegir quien si puede y quien no logear al panel(solo el root deberia hacerlo), hemos buscado como ocultar tablas también y encontré la siguiente manera;
[image: Configuración en la que podemos ocultar ciertas bases de datos.]

Pero el problema es que el usuario puede ir y quitar las bases de ese recuadro y ya las estaría viendo todas denuevo.

¿Como podría denegar el acceso a phpMyAdmin a ciertos usuarios? y ¿Como puedo ocultar ciertas bases de la vista de los demás?, estas dos preguntas contando con que el usuario de pruebas para esto ya esta con los mínimos permisos posibles (solo el de select).

Comment: Quieres que solo se puedan conectar directo desde la aplicación y no mediante ssh o mysql connect? A eso te refieres?

Comment: @AlfredoHernandezChiapas Exactamente eso busco, solo por medio de la aplicación!

Comment: @panmen, ¿Has podido solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panmen:

Al estar utilizando phpMyAdmin que debe estar montado en un servicio web, podrías denegar direcciones IP, a través de directivas propias del servicio web.

Si utilizas, por ejemplo, apache2.4, podrías añadir en un fichero .htaccess en la carpeta donde sirve tu web (DocumentRoot) las siguientes líneas:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Donde xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx es la IP.

2. En cuanto a permisos para usuarios particulares, podrías, por ejemplo, editar el fichero de configuración de phpMyAdmin config.inc.php que se encuentra en la ruta de instalación.

Un gran ejemplo podrías observarlo aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472492/deny-a-particular-users-login

3. Para ocultar BBDDs, este fichero también posee un array para insertar las que deseas ocultar:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|BD2|BD3';
```

Incluso lo podrías hacer por interfaz gráfica en las opciones de preferencias del phpMyAdmin. Ten en cuenta que ocultar una BD no quiere decir que un usuario no pueda ejecutar alguna query sobre esta, por lo que podrían crear, actualizar o borrar datos si tienen permisos. Lo más recomendable sería modificar los permisos de los usuarios que tienes creado para esta BD.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036547/mysql-grant-read-only-options

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Excelente, no tenia idea de ello!, muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho!

Comment: Me alegro @panmen. ¡Un saludo!